# GWT Flow Table fill cell

Tags: gwt

In GWT, I am trying to get a FlexTable with buttons in the grid so that clicking one of the buttons leads to something happening. However, when I look at the result in the browser, I get the following:

```
+-+-+ +-+  
|a|b| |c|  
+-+-+ +-+  
  |e|      
+-+-+-+-+-+
|d|h|i|f|g|
+-+-+-+-+-+
  |j|      
  +-+      
  |k|
  +-+
```

whereas what I want is this:

```
+-+---+---+
|a| b | c |
+-+---+-+-+
| | e | | |
| +-+-+ | |
| |h|i|f|g|
|d+-+-+ | |
| | j | | |
| +---+-+-+
| |   k   |
+-+-------+
```

I tried using `table.getFlexCellFormatter().setColSpan(row, col, span)` as recommended in the API, but this led to the first result above. Any ideas on how I should proceed?

@Stefan: my code is

```
public MyPanel() {
    Button b;
    FlexTable ft = new FlexTable();
    ClickHandler click = new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick() {
            // do something here with the button that was clicked
        }
    }
    b = new Button("a");
    b.addClickHandler(click);
    ft.setWidget(0, 0, b);
    // do the same for button "b" at (0,1), "c" at (0,3), "d" at (1,0), "e" at (1,1),
    // "f" at (1,3), "g" at (1,4), "h" at (2,1), "i" at (2,2), "j" at (3,1), "k" at (4,1)
    ft.getFlexCellFormatter().setColSpan(0, 1, 2);
    ft.getFlexCellFormatter().setColSpan(0, 3, 2);
    ft.getFlexCellFormatter().setRowSpan(1, 0, 4);
    ft.getFlexCellFormatter().setColSpan(1, 1, 2);
    ft.getFlexCellFormatter().setRowSpan(1, 3, 3);
    ft.getFlexCellFormatter().setRowSpan(1, 4, 3);
    ft.getFlexCellFormatter().setColSpan(3, 1, 2);
    ft.getFlexCellFormatter().setColSpan(4, 1, 4);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting the colspan and rowspan on a table cell doesn't change the adjacent cells index, it just shoves them out of the way. For example, to achieve this table:

```
+-+-+
|a|b|
| |-+
|a|c|
+-+-+
```

We use:

```
ft.setWidget(0, 0, a);
ft.setWidget(0, 1, b);
ft.setWidget(1, 0, c); // !!!
ft.getFlexCellFormatter().setRowSpan(0,0,2);
```

See, widget `c` is in the first cell that belongs to the first row. It may help to see things this way if you consider the HTML that would be generated:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rolspan="2">a</td><td>b</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Adjust your cell indexes and everything should line up the way you want them to:

```
ft.setWidget(0, 0, a);
ft.setWidget(0, 1, b);
ft.setWidget(0, 2, c);
ft.setWidget(1, 0, d);
ft.setWidget(1, 1, e);
ft.setWidget(1, 2, f);
ft.setWidget(1, 3, g);
ft.setWidget(2, 0, h);
ft.setWidget(2, 1, i);
ft.setWidget(3, 0, j);
ft.setWidget(4, 0, k);
ft.getFlexCellFormatter().setColSpan(0, 1, 2);
ft.getFlexCellFormatter().setColSpan(0, 2, 2);
ft.getFlexCellFormatter().setRowSpan(1, 0, 4);
ft.getFlexCellFormatter().setColSpan(1, 1, 2);
ft.getFlexCellFormatter().setRowSpan(1, 2, 3);
ft.getFlexCellFormatter().setRowSpan(1, 3, 3);
ft.getFlexCellFormatter().setColSpan(3, 0, 2);
ft.getFlexCellFormatter().setColSpan(4, 0, 4);
```

Comment: Although this does partially solve the problem, it does not solve the problem of the buttons expanding to **completely** fill the cells.

Comment: As indicated above, I want, for example, the "e" button to be as wide as the "h" and "i" buttons combined.

Comment: That is a matter of style. Set the button width and height to `100%` and they will completely fill their container.

Comment: This worked for width but not height (i.e., buttons "d", "f", and "g" are still not lining up.)

Comment: Ah... yes. Sorry, `height: 100%` doesn't work within a rowspan. Regrettably, everything I can find doesn't list any sort of fix, other than not using tables. On that note, the [DockPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DockPanel.html) or [DockLayoutPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DockLayoutPanel.html) may be useful.

Comment: Even outside of a rowspan, it doesn't work: Button "i", which has two lines of text, is taller than button "h", which has only one.

Comment: I have also seen the fill issue, but not in all browsers. That is, it seems to work in webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari). Do anyone know if this is a standards compliance issue? Note that i see this whether I use rowspan or not.

Comment: Great explanation on how `colspans` and `rowspans` work in GWT / HTML - thanks @DannyKirchmeier, it helped me a lot!